# Migration VSS 6.0 to SVN

Tags: svn, migration, visual-sourcesafe

Try to convert VSS 6.0 to SVN with this tool [VSSMigrate](http://vssmigrate.codeplex.com/releases/view/32081). I got following Error.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'SourceSafeTypeLib.VSSDatabaseClass' to interface type 'SourceSafeTypeLib.IVSSDatabase'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{2A0DE0EE-2E9F-11D0-9236-00AA00A1EB95}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).   at SourceSafeTypeLib.VSSDatabaseClass.Open(String SrcSafeIni, String Username, String Password)
```

What i Know for this error is current migration tool can't support VSS 6.0 and only support VSS 2005.
So, Is there any other tools to Migrate VSS 6.0 to SVN

Comment: best bet is just archive the current VSS and just check the current structure into svn

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool:

http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/svn_importer_features.php#VSS

It is free, however I do not know if it is usefull.

They claim:

The vss2svn tool migrates and converts data from MS Visual SourceSafe to Subversion.

- External tool ss is used to access the VSS repository (part of VSS
  client distribution)
- The transformation preserves revisions, authors, commit messages and
  dates of commits
- Logging (output to console, logging level) can be tuned in
  configuration file (using log4j configuration)

Comment: vss2svn doesn't move VSS 6.0. You need to have the VSS that shipped with 2005 for it to work. Wanna know how I know? I just tried it lol

Answer (score 1):

I helped write one on [codeplex](http://vss2svn.codeplex.com/), from an existing app. It worked well for me, was easy but took a long time to grab the gigabyte of historical data and commit it all to SVN.

I tried to make it as easy as possible. Of course, if you don't want any history the easiest way is just to checkout the entire VSS DB and add it to a new SVN repo using [in-place commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678437/svn-in-place-import-and-checkout).